# Visual Studio SQL Server database not migrating successfully because of missing column that seems to be present

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

At one point a few years ago I setup a project in Visual Studio to output to an Azure SQL V12 database, and tried to use `sqlcmd` with migration scripts (I say this also to point out that at one point everything did work, and everything discussed below made it into production).

My postdeployment script looks something like this:

```
PRINT N'Starting post deployment';
:setvar WorkDirectory "F:\path\to\scripts"
PRINT N'Starting 1.01';
:r $(WorkDirectory)\1.01\Deployment.sql
PRINT N'Starting 1.02';
:r $(WorkDirectory)\1.02\Deployment.sql
PRINT N'Starting 1.03'; :r $(WorkDirectory)\1.03\Deployment103.sql
PRINT N'Starting 1.04'; :r $(WorkDirectory)\1.04\Deployment104.sql
```

After not making any changes to the project (not consciously anyway), I've discovered that when I try and debug/generate the database and apply the migration scripts, I get an error because a column is referenced that doesn't exist on the table. The following is the offending part from the `Deployment104.sql` file:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM sys.columns 
               WHERE Name = N'MissingColumn'
                 AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TableA'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE TableA 
        ADD MissingColumn INT NOT NULL
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM information_schema.Routines
               WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'LIST_CODES'
                 AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' 
                 AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' )
BEGIN;
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.LIST_CODES as set nocount on;')
END
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].LIST_CODES 
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM CodesTable ct 
    LEFT JOIN TableA ta ON ct.CodeId = ta.CodeId
    WHERE ta.MissingColumn= 1999
    ORDER BY ct.CodeId
GO
```

The Db ends up partially created at this point. However, when I run that first check for whether the column exists, I actually get an entry back, implying that the column does exist in TableA. And yet I don't see it in Server Explorer (VS 2019 preview 16.4), and obviously the next part of the script doesn't see it either.

What am I doing wrong, and/or how can I make the script and the db agree as to which columns exist and which do not?

EDIT: as an update, while running the PostDeploymentScript fails, running the problematic script itself (Deployment104 in this case) works just fine, after which both the column and the stored procedure show up exactly as expected in the server explorer and can be referenced by other queries.

Comment: I assume you've refreshed the object explorer.

Comment: Yes, also restarted VS, and tried to rerun script, both manually (when it's generated) and through the start with debug options.  I don't care about the explorer, I just want the script to recognize that the column is created, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being splitting the command into its own batch, unfortunately not detectable through the posted code. The last instruction in `Deployment103.sql` was an `ALTER PROCEDURE`, which has to appear by itself in a batch, but the terminating `GO` was missing.

It looks like t-sql won't complain about this (because in the file, it does look like it's along in its batch). That led to the next instructions not working correctly, until the first `GO` statement in `Deployment104.sql`.

Adding the following `GO` resolved the issues (as does terminating Deployment103.sql with a `GO`)

```
PRINT N'Starting 1.03'; :r $(WorkDirectory)\1.03\Deployment103.sql
PRINT N'Starting 1.04'; 
GO
:r $(WorkDirectory)\1.04\Deployment104.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you are trying to add a non null column to an existing table.  You would need to add a default value for example of 0 or use a data type that supports null.  For example:

```
BEGIN
    alter table TableA 
    ADD MissingColumn int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
END
```

There is also a semicolon after the second BEGIN.

Current:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1 FROM information_schema.Routines
   WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'LIST_CODES'AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' )
BEGIN;
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.LIST_CODES as set nocount on;')
END
GO
```

Fixed:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1 FROM information_schema.Routines
   WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'LIST_CODES'AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' )
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.LIST_CODES as set nocount on;')
END
GO
```

After these changes I was able to get the statement to run in sqlfiddle.  Here is the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51253/3

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the issue here (the migration succeeds when not running from the postdeployment file).

Comment: I updated with an additional change.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: The semicolon in t-sql is...ignored at best? I'm not sure it was every actually added as something that's recognized. Regardless, these changes didn't solve the issue.